# How to show hover state for 1 card element that has handler event attached to multiple card elements?

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I'm a React beginner, trying to build a dashboard with card components. I have a React component that renders card elements, and for each card, has the same handler events for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. The expected behavior is to see `:hover` styles for when a mouse hovers over **one** widget. However, I'm seeming **ALL** the widgets with the `:hover` style. How can I change the code, so that only one that is moused over shows the hover state, and not all?

```
class Board extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) {
    this.showHoverBorder = this.showHoverBorder.bind(this);
    this.hideHoverBorder = this.hideHoverBorder.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      isHoverStyleOn: false,
      layouts: {
        lg: [
          { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
          { i: "b", x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
          { i: "c", x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
          { i: "d", x: 3, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
          { i: "e", x: 0, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1 },
          { i: "f", x: 0, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1 } 
        ]}
    }

    showHoverBorder() {
      this.setState({ isHoverStyleOn: true })
    }

    hideHoverBorder(hmm) {
      this.setState({ isHoverStyleOn: false })
    }
 }

render() {        
    let widget = "widget";
    if(this.state.isHoverStyleOn) {
      widget += ' widget-hover';
    } else { widget = "widget"; }

    return (
      <div layouts={this.state.layouts}>
        {this.state.layouts.lg.map((w) => ((
          <div key={w.i} className={widget}>
            <div className="widget-body">
              <div className="widget-bar" onMouseEnter={this.showHoverBorder} onMouseLeave={this.hideHoverBorder}>
              </div>
              <div className="widget-graph"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Board;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you extract the single items into a new class where you can handle the hover state as you want like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isHoverStyleOn: false,
        layouts: {
            lg: [
                { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
                { i: "b", x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
                { i: "c", x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
                { i: "d", x: 3, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
                { i: "e", x: 0, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1 },
                { i: "f", x: 0, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1 }
            ]
        }
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <div layouts={this.state.layouts}>
            {this.state.layouts.lg.map(w => (

                <Item w={w} />

            ))}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Extracted Item-Component

```
class Item extends Component {
  state = {
    active: false
  };

  hover = () => {
    this.setState({
        active: !this.state.active
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { w } = this.props;
    const { active } = this.state;

    return (
        <div key={w.i} className={!active ? "widget" : "widget widget-hover"}>
            <div className="widget-body">
                <div
                    className="widget-bar"
                    onMouseEnter={() => this.hover()}
                    onMouseLeave={() => this.hover()}
                >
                    <h1>test</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="widget-graph" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it with React, but if the only thing that's happening here is a CSS change on hover, then I think the solution should be CSS-based. No need to implement event listeners and add classes when all you need to do is add a :hover state to your CSS.

Comment: @develdevil, at some point, I will be selecting multiple cards with an active state, but the hover state would be distracting on the selected cards...so going with the event listeners unless there's alternative solution to that?

Comment: @ff9878 I still think you can define the hover state within CSS. The active state can be controlled through React by adding classes (as you are doing here for the hover state). Negating the hover effect should be easy to do - if your active style selector is ".active" then you just need to make it ".active, .active:hover" and the active state will negate the inactive hover state.